# Sign-in Dialog in Windows 8 app to use Live Connect services

Tags: c#, windows-8

When we call `LiveAuthClient.LoginAsync(...)` method from Windows 8 app, it will contact authorization server to get access token using OAuth 2.0 protocol (this initiates sign-in process). Then authorization server authenticates resource owner and gets whether owner grant/denies the permission. To do this it throws up UI dialogs on the user agent (in this case it is Windows 8 app).

I would like to know how this dialog pops up on our app. Will some information be sent by authorization server, using that Live SDK is popping up the dialog? I would like to know the origination point of the dialog. I appreciate if someone could help me in understanding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the LiveSDK myself but that sounds very much like a standard OAuth procedure like you would get when you use [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227025.aspx) yourself.
Not sure if I understood your question correctly, though. If you want to get more insight into the authentication broker you should have a look at the [sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122) mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: The information you provided helped me to understand web authentication broker concept. These links will provide more details into it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750287.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750286.aspx